# Toggle closest div hide other open divs

Tags: jquery, list, toggle

The following code allows me to toggle a div inside an LI, how can I adjust it so that when one div is open all other divs inside sibling LI's are closed?

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
$('.grey_button a').toggle(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.job_description').fadeIn(0);
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    //$(this).text($(this).text() == 'More Information' ? 'Hide Information' : 'More Information');
    return false;
},
    function() {
      $(this).closest('li').find('.job_description').fadeOut(0);
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
      //$(this).text($(this).text() == 'Hide Information' ? 'More Information' : 'Hide Information');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Example of HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="grey_button"><a href="" class="arrow">More information</a></div>
    <div class="job_description" style="display: none; ">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="grey_button"><a href="" class="arrow">More information</a></div>
    <div class="job_description" style="display: none; ">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="grey_button"><a href="" class="arrow">More information</a></div>
    <div class="job_description" style="display: none; ">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add one lookup for all `$('.job_description').hide()`.

If this would impact other sections of page with same class:

```
$('.grey_button a').toggle(function() { /* cache parent el */
    var $parent = $(this).closest('li'),
        $list = $parent.parent();
    $list.find('.job_description').hide();
    $list.find('.open').removeClass('open')

    $parent.find('.job_description').fadeIn(0);

    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    //$(this).text($(this).text() == 'More Information' ? 'Hide Information' : 'More Information');
    return false;
}, function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.job_description').fadeOut(0);
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    //$(this).text($(this).text() == 'Hide Information' ? 'More Information' : 'Hide Information');
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: That works well, except the siblings toggleClass isn't changing. The "open" class is remaining until that LI's grey_button a tag is clicked.

Comment: modified a bit...new variable $list

Comment: the simpler solution below would also work well, however would need modifying to look only within the `UL` if there were other similar `UL` in page

Comment: I noticed that when I open a div, then click open another div, then click on a div that's previously been open. I have to click on it twice to open it. Instead of only clicking on it once. And ideas?

Comment: likely due to toggleClass  ...try switch to 'addClass/removeClass' . If need to create a live demo in jsfiddle.net and post link here

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I think you might be able to reduce your code quite a bit:

```
$('.grey_button a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.job_description').hide(); // Reset
    $(this).closest('.job_description').fadeToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $('.grey_button a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.job_description').not($(this).closest('li').find('.job_description')).hide();
        $(this).toggleClass('open').parent('div').next('.job_description').toggle();
    });
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tNYC3/)